# getting rows from table based on related csv ids on another table

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I've been running a mysql query to get all rows based on FIND_IN_SET($bannerpageid,bf_relatedid)

$bannerpageid is a php variable declared at the top of each page.

banner_frames

```
  bf_ID  bf_relatedID   bf_content
  1      1,2,3,4        content
  2      2,4,6,8,10     content
  3      1,3,5,7,9      content
  ...
```

So $bannerpageid = 3, it would return rows 1 and 3 from the banner_frames table

It works, but it feels kind of backwards, I feel it would be better if the related bf_IDs were declared in a separate table banner page table. It would make the related id's easier to manage in the long run.

banner_page

```
  bp_ID  bp_relatedID
  1      1,2,3,4
  2      2,4,6,8,10
  3      1,3,5,7,9
  ...
```

banner_frames

```
  bf_ID  bf_content
  1      content
  2      content
  3      content
  ...
```

This time $bannerpageid relates to bp_ID in the banner_page table, so if $bannerpageid = 3, it would return rows 1 and 3 from the banner_frames table

I tried to write the mysql query to find in set based on a inner join, but I couldn't get it to execute the query correctly. So I'm a bit stumped.

If anyone has any suggestions I'd be really appreciative

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is your original MySQL code based on FIND_IN_SET?

Try with:

```
 SELECT banner_frames.bf_content FROM banner_frames JOIN banner_page ON (banner_page.bp_ID = banner_frames.bf_ID) WHERE FIND_IN_SET($bannerpageid, banner_page.bp_relatedID)
```

Comment: `mysql_select_db($database_dataconnection, $dataconnection);
$query_bannerframes = "SELECT * FROM banner_frames WHERE FIND_IN_SET($bannerpageid, bf_relatedID) AND bf_live = 1";
if(isset($query_bannerframes["bf_order"])){ $query_bannerframes .=" ORDER BY bf_order ASC";}
$bannerframes = mysql_query($query_bannerframes, $dataconnection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_bannerframes = mysql_fetch_assoc($bannerframes);
$totalRows_bannerframes = mysql_num_rows($bannerframes);`